# Is it possible to include a = sign in the "if ()"?

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote a line to add a total up the total value

```
int totalValue = value1 + value2 + value3;
```

Now I want to use an if statement to write `if (totalValue = 200);` but it gives me an error saying "Cannot convert from an int to a boolean type".

What should I do because I want to have four possible outcomes using `else if();
System.out.println();`

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison one.

Comment: What about `if (totalValue == 200)` and remove the `;`?

Answer (score 7):

```
if (totalValue == 200)
```

`=` is for assigning values, `==` is for comparing values.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator in Java only does assignment; you want to compare totalValue to 200, so you should use the `==` comparator operator.

```
if(totalValue = 200){
    ...
}
```

Do note that you shouldn't have a semicolon after an `if` statement, since then Java will basically ignore the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The = sign is the assignment operator.

Doing `if(totalValue = 200)` will actually assign 200 to totalValue.

What you need is the == operator

```
if(totalValue == 200)
{
System.out.println("200");
}
else if (totalValue == 100)
{
System.out.println("100");
} //...
```

Putting the line terminator at the end of if(totalValue == 200);
will terminate the conditional statement. This means that the statements below it will not only execute if the condition evaluates to true.

Also, I find it good practice to always put {} after the if() even with just one statement to prevent issues with scoping. Here's a link to show how this can happen (and prevented) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999473/apples-goto-fail-security-bug

Answer (score 0):

if you write if(totalValue = 19), it will evaluate if you can successfully assign 19 to totalValue.

Being successful or not, in Java is a Boolean, so it expects to evaluate a boolean.
The expression:

```
if((totalValue = 19) == True){ ... }
```

would be correct but also useless, in this case, because it will almost for sure assign successfully the value

if you wanna only check the value you must use `==`

Comment: `true` is spelled with a lowercase t in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but equality is `==` and assignment is `=`. Also, don't end your `if` statement with a semicolon or you terminate the body of the `if`.

```
// if (totalValue = 200);
if (totalValue == 200) {
    // Do stuff for when the value is 200
} else {
    // Do stuff when the value is not 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, the '=' operator in Java is used to assign values. However (maybe a little off-topic), the assignment itself evaluates to the assigned value, which can be reused in a boolean expression.

This can be used like in this loop, where the result of readLine is stored and compared to null in a single expression:

```
int value;
while ((value = reader.read()) != -1) {
    doSomething(value);          
}
```